# Why does saving a JavaScript regular expression to a variable produce different results when invoking the .test() method?

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone explain why saving this regex to a variable produces alternating true and false values, but using the literal produces true every time? Am I missing something obvious here? I'm certainly not a regex expert, but this seems like odd behavior to me.

```
var exp = /[\^~\\><\|"]/g;

exp.test('<abc'); // true

exp.test('<abc'); // false

exp.test('<abc'); // true

exp.test('<abc'); // false

/[\^~\\><\|"]/g.test('<abc'); // true

/[\^~\\><\|"]/g.test('<abc'); // true

/[\^~\\><\|"]/g.test('<abc'); // true

/[\^~\\><\|"]/g.test('<abc'); // true
```

[CodePen Demo (check the console)](http://codepen.io/evandull/full/GjcFo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because regular expression objects *save* their state, so when you call test *again* on the *same* object it tries to find the next match and fails.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

> test called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.

In the last examples, you are creating a *new* regular expression each time, so it matches every time.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the regex lesson :)

Comment: Question... since the regex object saves its state, why does the result toggle back to true on the third call?

Comment: @BrianFitzGerald: I'm not 100% sure, but probably because it hit the end of the string and looped back to the beginning.